# Appium Desktop could not start new session with iOS

Tags: ios, automated-tests, appium, appium-ios

I am using Appium Desktop, Version 1.0.0-beta.5 (https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases). It works fine with Android, but when I test iOS app, I get this error message about ideviceinstaller, as the screenshot below with desired capabilities settings:

[image]

I don't know if it is because this ipa file is not built with Developer Signature or if my desired capabilities settings missing something. Can some Appium experts help me out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you check the bundle id? if its correct and whether have you mentioned it in the `desired capabilities`? btw? are you able to launch the app in the device? does this error display in between ur tests?

Comment: I am able to install and launch the app on device. I also checked bundleId and added it in desired capabilities, but this message is still displayed and appium could not start a new session

Comment: If you are able install and launch the app through appium, then there is not any prblem with your desired capabilities then. I am still wondering, how does the app install and launch at first place, when the appium server is not created. The general process is, the session gets created at first place, followed by instrument install and launch. 

Can you check, if you are asserting the correct element in the first test script? I have seen quite a few cases where if the appium does not detect an element, it  displays this kind of error.